# parsing a xml file using javascript does not givethe required result

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to parse a XML-file using java-script. Actually, I read many tutorials to find out how to parse the data from the XML-file correctly, and I found that I am on the right way.
Concerning the loadXMLDoc(dname) function, I passed the path of the XML-file to loadXMLDoc function as follows:

```
var dname = "D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml";
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
```

But still the parsing does not give me the desired result, I want to display the name in the following tag

```
<name>Jane Austin</name>
```

but the web browser does not display it, I am using Chrome.
Please, (1) Let me know where my mistake is? (2)what extension the parser file should be saved under(.HTML/.js)

Please find below the XML-file and the java-script file

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <Schriftsteller>
     <Englischsprache>
        <Dichtung> 
       <fueller>
       <name>Jane Austin</name>
               <name>Rex Stout</name>
               <name>Dashiell Hammett</name>    
       </fueller>
    </Dichtung>
</Englischsprache>
  </Schriftsteller>
```

JavaScript File.html(Parser):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">   
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="readXML.css" type="text/css">
       <title>Read First Child</title>

        <!-- <xml ID="Schriftsteller" SRC="D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml"></xml> -->
        <script language="JavaScript">

         var dname = "D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml";
         function loadXMLDoc(dname)
              {
                 var xmlDoc;
                 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                 {
                  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                  xmlDoc.open("GET",dname,false);
                  xmlDoc.send();
                  return xmlDoc.responseXML;
                 }
                 // IE 5 and IE 6
                  else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
                  {
                   xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                   xmlDoc.async=false;
                   xmlDoc.load(dname);
                   return xmlDoc;
                  }
                    alert("Error loading document!");
                    return null;
              }

              function findWriter() 
              {
                 var schriftstellerKnoten, SpracheKnoten;
                 var FuellerKnoten, DichtungKnoten, Anzeige;

                 myXML = document.all(dname).XMLDocumentalert(dname);

                 SchriftstellerKnoten = myXML.documentElement;
                 SpracheKnoten = SchriftstellerKnoten.firstChild;
                 DichtungKnoten = SpracheKnoten.firstChild;
                 FuellerKnoten = DichtungKnoten.firstChild;
                 NameNode = FuellerKnoten.firstChild;
                 Anzeige = NameNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
                 document.write(Anzeige);
              }
           </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadXMLDoc(dname)">
  <span ID="blueBack">Read firstChild</span>
  <div>
  <form name="show">
  <input type=text name="me">
  <input type="button" value="Display Writer"
      onClick="findWriter()">
  </form>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: That is not even close to well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1):

First your XML-Document has to be well-formed.

So for every tag you open add another tag to close it (like you do with the name-tag). The closing tag has to be same as the opening, except for a `/` in the beginning

Also you have to watch the case (well-formed XML is case-sensitive). The tag

`<EnglischSprache>` is different from `<Englischsprache>`

Try it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Schriftsteller>
  <EnglischSprache>
    <Dichtung> 
      <fueller>
        <name>Jane Austin</name>
        <name>Rex Stout</name>
        <name>Dashiell Hammett</name>    
      </fueller>
    </Dichtung> 
  </EnglischSprache>
</Schriftsteller>
```

Then in the JS-File, maybe you should try calling the function loadXMLDoc.

Looks like you're just defining it.

Try it like this:

```
<body onload="loadXMLDoc(dname)">
```

Better now?

Comment: I modified the xml-file and appended the onload() function as you suggested, but, still the parsing does not occure. Please see the modified post above.

Comment: There are a lot of small mistakes left:

- What is `document`?

- What should be shown where? You don't even say that there should appear anything on your HTML-Page (Maybe you mean `Documentar.show.me.value` to show something on your page, but i have not seen anything like this in my life) Try assigning elemts with `document.getElementById("exampleId").innerHTML` to elements of your body

Comment: What if I used the following syntax:

Comment: Anzeige = NameNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
document.write(Anzeige);

Comment: You try to load your XML file in the variable `myXML` by calling `document.all(dname).XMLDocumentalert(dname)`. I think you should try loading it with the function `loadXMLDoc`. It should look like `myXML = loadXMLDoc(dname)`. The rest of the code doesn't look that bad, should probably work...
Maybe you could also try to find errors in your file by adding 
Message Boxes like `alert("error");` so you can see where your code stops working. That's the way i try to compile html-files.